# SQL: Outer Joins with one-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, join

So, I'm working on my outer join skills with pure SQL (MySQL is the DBMS I'm using). I've got four tables: People, Address, Phone, Email. All are pretty self explanatory. People is the main table, every record in the other three contains a foreign key references the People table.

I want to write a query that will do outer joins on all four tables. Ideally, here is what I want the results to look like:

```
Name         Address         Phone         Email
Bob          5 Steel Dr      512-222-1358  bob@gmail.com
Bob                          212-333-4444  bob@aol.com
Bob                                        bob@hotmail.com
```

The idea is to have the address/phone/email records not repeat at all. The info from the People table can repeat, that's fine, but I would be trying to avoid repeats from the others.

Here is a very, very crude version of what I'm going for.

```
select p.name, e.email, a.address
from people p
left join email e on p.pid = e.pid
left join address a on p.pid = a.pid
where p.pid = 1;
```

It doesn't work, though. It repeats all the records that match each other.

Is there any way to get the effect I'm going for? I'm a bit rusty on outer joins.

Comment: the  query seems right .. check for the data ..

Answer (score 2):

Not without jumping through a lot of unreliable "hoops", usually involving session variables.

You are overlooking that the result set you want implies relationships that are just not there. `5 Steel Dr`, `512-222-1358`, and `bob@gmail.com` have no direct connection. Your results slightly imply the phone number may be present at the address. What you have are 3 lists that happen to be aligned side by side.

A query that outputs this kind of result is the equivalent of giving each row a "line number".

Comment: +1 Very nice way to explain it—that there is no relationship between the entries that happen to end up together on the rows of output.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution to get the output like you describe in a single SQL query.

Which shouldn't be surprising, because that output violates [Fourth Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form).

Honestly, I would run three queries, one for People joined to Address, one for People joined to Phone, and one for People joined to Email.

```
select p.name, a.address
from people p
inner join address a on p.pid = a.pid
where p.pid = 1;

select p.name, ph.phone
from people p
inner join phone ph on p.pid = ph.pid
where p.pid = 1;

select p.name, e.email
from people p
inner join email e on p.pid = e.pid
where p.pid = 1;
```

Then combine the results however you want in application code.

Comment: Exactly so:  *"my name is Bob, I live at one address, and I have four e-mail accounts that you know about. Oh yeah, and I have a 'personal cell-phone,' a 'work cell-phone,' and a house that's old enough to still have a copper wire connected to it."*  Your schema needs to be able to handle this, with separate tables, *e.g.*: `PEOPLE`, `PEOPLE-PHONE`,  `PEOPLE-EMAIL`. There are at least *three* one-to-many relationships here, none related to any other.